# Passing ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME between Activities

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, android-activity

I am having trouble with passing data between two activities within my application. My `ActivityOne` populates a list of contacts from the phone. The user is then able to select a contact which will take them to `ActivityTwo`. Here is how I have written the Intent to go from ActivityOne to ActivityTwo after a contact is selected:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
    i.putExtra("name", ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

In ActivityTwo's `onCreate()` method, I have included this code in order to restore the data that was passed:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    name = extras.getString("name");
}
```

ActivityOne properly populates the contact list with the correct names, but when I try to use the name that is passed to ActivityTwo, it defaults to `display_name` instead of the contact's actual name.

Is there something that I've done wrong or something that I am overlooking?

Comment: ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME well get you the default value of it you need to get the name of selected item it self and pass it to bundle

Comment: are your listview item contain only the name of contacts???

Comment: Yes, my ListView item only displays the names of the contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this code and feed me back ?

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {        
    String name =  ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
    i.putExtra("name", name);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: That returns `android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@41e9e5d8_1`. I have also tried `ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME.indexOf(position)` but that did not work either.

Comment: could you post your Listview code so i can test it ??

Comment: @Jack take look on edited answer i test the code and it return the name of selected list item  for me

Comment: thanks, that seems to work. Not that it matters, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this using the `ListView l` object or without casting `View v` to a `TextView` object.

Comment: the another way to get using the id  , but you will need to making query to contact provider with id to get the name , and you can get  object that contain in item but it will need some operation on it to get the name including some casting , so i find it easy way to making cast once